# Sending E-mail Hotmail Account via Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, email, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I just write this code in Python under Raspbian OS:

```
import smtplib

from = '****@hotmail.de'
to   = '****@hotmail.de'
msg  = 'Testmail'

usr = '****@hotmail.de'
psw = '****'

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.live.de',25)
server.login (usr,psw)
server.sendmail (from, to, msg)
server.quit()
```

And get following Error-Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ail.py", line 1, in <module>
  import smtplib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 46, in <module>
  import email.utils
  File "/home/pi/email.py", line 6, in <module>
  smtp =smtplib.SMTP('smtp.live.com',25)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SMTP'
```

What is my fault? Could somebody help me - please?

Regards

Comment: Your edit made the question and both answers completely useless to anyone searching for the same problem in the future, so I've rolled it back. If you have a completely new question, post a new question, don't try to change this one into a different question than it started out as.

Comment: ok, I postet a new Question. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you named your script `email.py`, or maybe an earlier version of it. That means that it shadows the standard-library `email` module/package. So, when `smtplib` tries to `import email` or `import email.utils`, it gets *your* code instead of the stdlib code it wants.

The solution is to rename your script to not match any of the [stdlib modules and packages](http://docs.python.org/2/library/index.html) (or at least not any of the ones you're directly or indirectly using).

If you've already renamed it to `ail.py` (as the traceback seems to suggest) and it's still causing problems, make sure to delete your original `email.py`, and any .pyc/.pyo files of the same name. As long as they're in the current working directory (or elsewhere on `sys.path`), they can still interfere with the stdlib.

Comment: @user1557170: That's obviously a completely separate problem. You can't use SO as a "progressive debugging" service where you keep adding new bugs onto your existing question. Post a new question for a new problem.